# Build and Link using Makefiles for C/C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

Below is my makefile

```
#Makefile for beaglebone
#General tools
CC=gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
RM = rm -fr
TARGET = beaglebone
# Source locations
BACNET_CORE = ../../src
BACNET_INCLUDE = ../../include
BACNET_HANDLER = ../../demo/handler
BACNET_OBJECT = ../../demo/object
BACNET_DEMO = ../../demo

# local files for this project
CSRC = main.c  arcnet.c  bip-init.c  dlmstp.c  dlmstp_linux.c ethernet.c rs485.c timer.c device.c

#common demo files needed
DEMOSRC = $(BACNET_DEMO)/handler/txbuf.c $(BACNET_DEMO)/handler/h_npdu.c $(BACNET_DEMO)/handler/s_iam.c $(BACNET_DEMO)/handler/noserv.c

# core BACnet stack files
CORESRC =  $(BACNET_CORE)/crc.c $(BACNET_CORE)/npdu.c $(BACNET_CORE)/bacdcode.c $(BACNET_CORE)/bacint.c $(BACNET_CORE)/bacreal.c \
    $(BACNET_CORE)/bacstr.c $(BACNET_CORE)/iam.c $(BACNET_CORE)/rp.c $(BACNET_CORE)/wp.c $(BACNET_CORE)/whois.c $(BACNET_CORE)/bacaddr.c  \
        $(BACNET_CORE)/abort.c  $(BACNET_CORE)/reject.c $(BACNET_CORE)/bacerror.c  $(BACNET_CORE)/bacapp.c

## Include Directories
INCLUDES = -I. -I$(BACNET_INCLUDE)
INCLUDES += -I$(BACNET_OBJECT)
INCLUDES += -I$(BACNET_HANDLER)

# Source to Object conversion
COBJ = $(CSRC:.c=.o)
DEMOOBJ = $(DEMOSRC:.c=.o)
COREOBJ = $(CORESRC:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(COBJ) $(DEMOOBJ) $(COREOBJ)
#Build and Link the objects

all: $(TARGET)

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $@
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS) -o  $(TARGET) 

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(TARGET)
```

when issue make I get the .o files created and it does not creates an executable. I get the output as follows:

```
s_iam.c:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `bip_get_my_address'
../../demo/handler/s_iam.o: In function `Send_I_Am_Unicast':
s_iam.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `bvlc_send_pdu'
../../demo/handler/noserv.o: In function `handler_unrecognized_service':
noserv.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `bip_get_my_address'
noserv.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `bvlc_send_pdu'
../../src/bacapp.o: In function `bacapp_copy':
bacapp.c:(.text+0x7ac): undefined reference to `datetime_copy_date'
bacapp.c:(.text+0x7bb): undefined reference to `datetime_copy_time'
../../src/bacapp.o: In function `bacapp_snprintf_value':
bacapp.c:(.text+0xba4): undefined reference to `bactext_object_type_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xbbc): undefined reference to `bactext_event_state_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xbce): undefined reference to `bactext_engineering_unit_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xbe1): undefined reference to `bactext_binary_polarity_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xbf0): undefined reference to `bactext_binary_present_value_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xbfa): undefined reference to `bactext_reliability_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `bactext_device_status_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xc0e): undefined reference to `bactext_segmentation_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xc18): undefined reference to `bactext_node_type_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xc45): undefined reference to `bactext_day_of_week_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xc84): undefined reference to `bactext_month_name'
bacapp.c:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `bactext_object_type_name'
../../src/bacapp.o: In function `bacapp_parse_application_data':
bacapp.c:(.text+0x10bd): undefined reference to `datetime_set_date'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [beaglebone] Error 1
```

Kindly tell me where I am going wrong and many thanks for your help and suggestions!!!

Regards,
Gibson

Comment: Show the commands run by `make`. Use `remake -x` or `make --trace` to debug your `Makefile`; maybe you forgot linking with some library providing `bactext_*` functions. BTW, C is not C++, you have to choose one!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your object files are in a bit of a random order, so that later object files refer to symbol defined in earlier object files and this is why the link fails.

Try the following. Replace:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS) -o  $(TARGET)
```

With:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ -Wl,--start-group $(OBJECTS) -Wl,--end-group
```

That is going to make `ld` to scan the object files for missing symbols a few times (like MSVC does).